# Issue with single quote in multiple line json data in php

Tags: php, json

```
$arr = '{
    
    "38": {
        "email": "zhangshizhu08@163.com",
        "history": "Baldwin's,DNW"
    },
    "39": {
        "email": "john@filcombe.com",
        "history": "Spink"
    },
   
}';

$p_array = json_decode($dat,true);
print_r($p_array);
```

Comment: Hi Deepak, could you please explain your problem in more detail? I see that the JSON is a valid JSON. What is the actual problem are you having with single quotes?

Comment: Ohh, I do understand, you are unable to enclose the text within a string, as the text has both double quotes and single quotes, right? In that case you can use PHP HEREDOC https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use heredoc this way

```
$jsonString = <<<JSON 
{
    "38": {
        "email": "zhangshizhu08@163.com",
        "history": "Baldwin's,DNW"
    },
    "39": {
        "email": "john@filcombe.com",
        "history": "Spink"
    }
}
JSON;
$p_array = json_decode($jsonString, true); 
print_r($p_array);
```

Hope this helps.